# Why does my View Controller recognize that the Navigation Bar is present only sometimes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've searched for an answer, but I can't seem to find one, so I've resorted to asking a question here. If this is a duplicate, please point me to the correct page.

I have a View Controller in which on viewDidLoad I create a UITableView and set it's frame to

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

if there is something in the UITableView. If there is nothing in it, I set the UITableView's frame to

```
CGRectMake(0, 135, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

So that I can display a message above it.

In this ViewController, I have an add button that when pressed, I create a new view in which you can enter in or modify existing info, and then press a save or delete button, which removes the view from the superview and resets the frame of the UITableView back to either

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

or

```
CGRectMake(0, 135, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Depending on if there is anything in the UITableView. (If the UITableView is empty, it is set to the second one, if it has at least one row it is set to the first).

The issue I'm having is that sometimes when the UITableView is set back to (0, 0) after having pressed the save or delete button, the UITableView's first row is covered by the navigation bar, instead of below it.

How can I make sure that my UITableView is set below the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a XIB file you can add a simulated navigation bar to your view controller which allows you to adjust your elements appropriately so they do not intersect.

[image]

Programmatically you can set a content inset to the tableview to be the height of the navigation bar + the status bar like follows:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0,0,0);
```

Using an inset when you scroll the table content will go behind the Navigation bar, so if you don't want this to happen you should change the frame like you're doing. However,

```
CGRectMake(0, 135, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Will probably behave strangely because you've pushed part of the view off the screen because you've set the height to be the height of the screen, but you've offset the frame by 135. This would be the proper rect:

```
CGRectMake(0, 135, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 135)
```

Personally I'd recommend you'd use an inset, but if you move the frame make sure you subtract the y-offset from the height.

Comment: I've set up everything programmatically for this. Unfortunately, your answer didn't fix my problem. Out of curiosity, why would setting it to self.view.frame.size.height without subtracting the y position cause it to act strangely? I thought that self.view.frame.size.height just returned a number.

Comment: it does but that number in your context would be your full screen height. Since you're moving your frame down by 135 part of your view will not actually be displayed because it would be outside the window bounds. Does your problem only show up after the tableView had loaded and you change the frame? Can you include all of your viewDidLoad code and anything you have that adjusts the height?